# регулярное выражение для выделения имени файла и версии

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки, разделение-строк

Есть имена файла, которые состоят из двух частей - имя, содержащее буквы, цифры и тире, а также версия - всё, что идёт потом

Для выделения имени и версии использую простую регулярку

```
^([a-zA-Z_-]+)(.*)$
```

Подскажите, как её модифицировать, чтобы

1. если между именем и версией стоят тире, то они игнорируются (не включаются в имя)
2. если название файла заканчивается на `.tar`, то игнорируется `.tar` (не включается в версию)

Понятно, что это можно сделать уже после получения имени и версии очень легко, но хочется именно в рамках одной регулярки

Т.е. чтобы для

```
my-file-test-1x1.-.121.tar

my-file-test-1x1.-.121

my-file-test1x1.-.121

my-file-test----1x1.-.121

my-file-test-1x1.-.121
```

во всех случаях было бы имя `my-file-test`, и версия `1x1.-.121`

Comment: пишите, что имя содержит буквы-цифры, а регулярка ваша про цифры ничего не знает. Да и суда по результату, цифры в названия не входят.

Comment: `(?>\.tar)?` в конце добавьте

Comment: `/^(.+?)-*(\d+x\d+\.-\.\d+)(?:\.[a-z]{1,4})?$/` такое подойдёт?

Comment: Может, `^(.*?)-*(\d+x\d+\W+\d+)`? См. https://regex101.com/r/rf1ggG/2

Answer (score 0):

> во всех случаях было бы имя my-file-test, и версия 1x1.-.121

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const a = [
    'my-file-test-1x1.-.121.tar',
    'my-file-test-1x1.-.121',
    'my-file-test1x1.-.121',
    'my-file-test----1x1.-.121',
    'my-file-test-1x1.-.121',
  'my-file---xxxx-test-1x1.-.121'
]
const r = /^(-*[a-z]+){3}|\d.+\d+(?=\.tar|$)/g
a.forEach(v => console.log(v.match(r)))
```

Comment: как-то не так срабатывает, да и частный случай это - вот такую строку не обработает `my-file---xxxx-test-1x1.-.121`

Comment: @Zhihar, такой строки не было в тексте вопроса... :) И какой должен быть от нее результат? И что значит "как-то не так срабатывает"? Я показываю имя файла и его версию.